# How to renumber a list of invoice line numbers using SQL query (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table of itemized invoices with duplicate line numbers that need to be renumbered. I need to loop through each invoice and renumber the line numbers so the line numbers can read 1,2,3,4 and so on.

I have used the following query to update one invoice:

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0

UPDATE Invoice_Itemized
SET @counter = LineNum = @counter + 1 
WHERE Invoice_Number = 619558
```

How can I update all invoices with duplicate Line Numbers in my invoice itemized table?

Currently my table looks like Image 1 and would like it to look like Image 2 after running query.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXcPH.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ntv5.png)

Comment: Please post the table DDL and the table's content in text form next time, so it's easier to write a response that you don't actually need to rewrite when applying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ROW_NUMBER()` window function gives a non-repeated incremental number for each indicated partition. Try the following:

```
;WITH NewInvoiceLineNumber AS
(
    SELECT
        I.*,
        NewLineNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                I.Invoice_Number
            ORDER BY
                I.LineNum ASC,
                I.ItemNum ASC)
    FROM
        ItemizedInvoices AS I
)
UPDATE I SET
    LineNum = NewLineNumber
FROM
    NewInvoiceLineNumber AS I
```

To validate the result before doing the update, you can change the `UPDATE` for a `SELECT`.

```
;WITH NewInvoiceLineNumber AS
(
    SELECT
        I.*,
        NewLineNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                I.Invoice_Number
            ORDER BY
                I.LineNum ASC,
                I.ItemNum ASC)
    FROM
        ItemizedInvoices AS I
)
SELECT
    I.*
FROM
    NewInvoiceLineNumber AS I
```